# FUSE Extended Attributes

Tags: fuse, file-attributes

I'm trying to implement a FUSE file system including the ability to set/get extended file attributes. In this case, the attribute that I am interested in is one to create a boolean condition to mark a file as encrypted. Let's say that I have a file called test.txt. From a terminal window, I can easily do the following:

> setfattr -n user.encrypted -v 1 test.txt
>
> getfattr -n user.encrypted test.txt

and get the output:

> # file: test.txt
>
> user.encrypted="1"

So, I know that my system is correctly set to work with extended attributes.

But I'm stuck on setting and getting these attributes programatically from within FUSE. For example, I have the following function:

```
/* File open operation */
int bb_open(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    int retstat = 0;
    int fd;
    int isEncrypted;
    char user[] = "user";
    char encAttr[] = "encrypted";
    
    fd = open(path, fi->flags);
    if (fd < 0)
        retstat = bb_error("bb_open open");
          
    log_msg("\nAbout to get encryption attribute\n");  
    /* get the encryption attribute */
    isEncrypted = fgetxattr(fd, user, encAttr, 1);
    
    log_msg("\nisEncrypted: %d\n", isEncrypted);

    return retstat;
}
```

When I run this, even after setting this attribute from the command line, fgetxattr always fails (i.e. it returns a value of -1). The output in my log file is:

> isEncrypted = -1

Clearly I'm calling this function incorrectly, but I don't know how to correct this. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the following functions in your FUSE filesystem:

- [listxattr](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html#ab4a9c361ce48406f07d5a08ab03f5de8) to get the list of supported Extended Attributes
- [getxattr](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html#ae21503c64fe2990c8a599f5ba339a8f2) to get the value of Extended Attribute